# AEM Forms. Meaning of Document of Records

Tags: adobe, aem

I am learning AEM forms. I have come across the term DoR(document of records) in multiple places, but don't understand what it really means and how it is connected to AEM forms.

If someone could explain with an example, it would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**In super simple terms:**
- AEM Forms (html based) allows the end-user to complete & fill out forms.
- The DOR which AEM Forms (aka Livecycle in the background) can also generate a PDF representation of the AEM Form (html)
.


**Typical Example scenario:**
- User wants to sign up for health insurance.
- User fills in New Health Application Form online (AEM HTML Form) on the health insurance's website.
- User submits the form.
- The AEM forms server recieves the submission and does the following:
a) submits data to back-end health insurance system.
b) generates a DOR and saves it to an ECM (eg: sharepoint).
c) generates and send out an email to the user with the DOR attached to an email.

Answer (score 1):

From AEM official documents at: https://helpx.adobe.com/aem-forms/6-2/generate-document-of-record-for-non-xfa-based-adaptive-forms.html

> After submitting a form, your customers generally want to keep a record, in print or in document format, of the information they have filled in the form for their future reference. This is referred to as a **Document of Record (DoR)**.

As explained by other, DoR is the data capture in a PDF or PDF/A form for the submitted data by a user and captured in AEM forms system.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as a hard copy version (PDF) of the form (HTML) that can be saved (on a file system or a printed copy) for record keeping purposes. Hence document of record (DOR)

Answer (score 0):

Document of record refers to a document created for record keeping purposes. From http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/record.html:

> Document that memorializes and provides objective evidence of activities performed, events occurred, results achieved, or statements made. Records are created/received by an organization in routine transaction of its business or in pursuance of its legal obligations. A record may consist of two or more documents.

In AEM Forms, a document of record means a document that is not used only for data capture, it is used for record keeping, and therefore is preserved for long periods of time (in most cases, this means a PDF or PDF/A document).